# How To Move 3 Popular Countries at the top of the dropdown menu

Tags: html, laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-blade

I currently have a country `dropdown` menu that displays all countries. Normally my users select between "United States", "United Kingdom", or "Canada". I don't want my users to scroll all the way down to the list to select their country, so is there a way that I can brings those 3 countries at the top of the list?

[image]

As you can see from the image that's something that I want. Of course right now I have those 3 countries hard coded. I feel that it isn't a good practice to hard code it especially since I already have those 3 countries in the list, so there's no need to hard code it.

As you can see the image, that's my code displaying the countries. You can also see that I'm hard coding the 3 countries. Below is the code I added so that you can see.

```html
<select name="country" id="country" class="custom-select" data-live-search="true" data-default="{{ old('country') }}">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    @foreach ($countries as $key=>$val)
        @if($key == old('country'))
            <option value="{{ $key }}" selected="selected">{{ $val }}</option>
        @else
            <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $val }}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I appreciate any help on this! Thank you!

Comment: The answer will likely depend on how you are receiving your country list (database, stored array, ?) and how you are receiving your list of popular countries. I see no issue in the way you are doing things unless you want to pop off the hard-coded countries from the `$countries` array to prevent dups, or if you want to pull in popular countries from a database.

Comment: what is the format of countries array ? I'll give you the solution

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your countries table in which you can differentiate between your normal countries and your popular countries.

#### Option 1: *Favorites*

Append a `favorite` column to your table, as `TINYINT` (`boolean` in a migration). Then, simply set this to `1` (`true`) for these 3 countries, and then you can append an `orderBy` to your query:
`$query->orderByDesc('favorite')`

This will return the 3 favorited countries at the top

#### Option 2: *Order*

I am more of a fan of this approach, as it's definitely more configurable. Append an `order` column to your table, as unsigned `INT` (`unsignedInteger` in migration). Then, set the order value from 0 or 1 (I personally prefer 1, as it's more human readable, but you have to keep that in mind when changing/updating the order), to how many countries you have (-1 if you started at 0), in the way you wish them to be displayed. Then, in your query: `$query->orderBy('order')`. You can even add this as [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes) to never forget to order. This way, you can always say you want the UK above the US, or vice versa, or change it if you realise that one country is more popular than the other.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to adding extra column or table. You can use `arrays` options as a solution. Make two arrays separately with the following conditions. Then convert the query output to an array using `->toArray()`. Finally merge two arrays using `array_merge()` and pass to the view. I suppose you make a list of countries with `id` and `country_name` fields, like this:

**Controller**:

```
$my_countries = \App\Country::select(['id','country_name'])->where('country_name', 'United States')->orWhere('country_name', 'United Kingdom')->orWhere('country_name', 'Canada')->get()->toArray();
$countries = \App\Country::select(['id','country_name'])->whereNotIn('country_name', ['United States', 'United Kingdom', 'Canada'])->get()->toArray();
$all_countries  = array_merge($my_countries , $countries);   
return view('your_view', ['all_countries' => $all_countries]);
```

**View**:

```
<select name="country">
    @foreach($all_countries as $country )
        <option value="{{ $country['id'] }}">{{ $country['country_name'] }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```